# How do I discount the original sell price based on the quantity of either one OR all the products in the cart?

Tags: drupal, ubercart, discount

How do I discount ALL products in the cart based on the quantity of any and/or all products purchased? For example, when the user buys a totale of 10 products (any combination of products), the products are discounted of $5.00 each.

I've looked at the following modules. I don't believe they are the solution. (Some are just problematic.)

- uc_bulk_discount
- uc_discounts_alt
- uc_pricelist

Comment: cant post comments yet, just wanted to asked if you've seen http://drupal.org/project/uc_discounts_alt

Comment: Sam, Yes, I did see uc_discouts feature list, but thanks for the cattle-prod, because on second reading its worth trying ... the feature listing touches on the requirement and as feature lists go, sometimes there's something missing. So, thanks, I'll give that a shot, i.e. install the mod and look closer. Regards .. cfusch

Comment: SOLVED! - Thank you, Sam! After a review of Sam's suggestion regarding uc_discounts_alt, the requirement has been met.  The module provides the discounting functionality required by the client.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the comments. Converted to community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@Sam Healey wrote:

> just wanted to asked if you've seen http://drupal.org/project/uc_discounts_alt

The OP wrote:

> Sam, Yes, I did see uc_discouts feature list, but thanks for the cattle-prod, because on second reading its worth trying ... the feature listing touches on the requirement and as feature lists go, sometimes there's something missing. So, thanks, I'll give that a shot, i.e. install the mod and look closer.
>
> SOLVED! - Thank you, Sam! After a review of Sam's suggestion regarding uc_discounts_alt, the requirement has been met. The module provides the discounting functionality required by the client.